How to Hide Filters Based on Row-Level Security (RLS) in Apache Superset 4.0?
I'm using Apache Superset 4.0 and have implemented Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) and Row-Level Security (RLS) to manage data access for different user roles. However, I want to hide specific filters on dashboards based on these RLS rules. Specifically, I want to ensure that certain filters are only visible to users with specific roles.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Created user roles (admin, manager, employee).
Applied RLS rules to restrict data visibility based on user roles.
Created separate dashboards or tabs for different user roles, each containing relevant filters.
Used RBAC to control access to these dashboards.
However, this approach involves creating multiple dashboards or tabs, which can be cumbersome. Ideally, I would like to conditionally hide filters within the same dashboard based on the user's role.
Questions:
Is there a way to hide or show dashboard filters based on RLS or user roles in Superset 4.0?
Can custom JavaScript be used in Superset to achieve this, and if so, how?
Are there any other recommended practices for handling this requirement in Superset?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I tried exploring trhe superset and alos some content on internet, but didnot find any solution
